# How to use send in Locomotive Js

Tags: node.js, express, locomotivejs

How can I use send() in  action of controller in locomotive Js. I think LCM only provides render().
Can some one guide me in this regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locomotivejs is just an extension of Express, meaning a Loco app is an Express app. From the docs:

> ### Request and Response
>
> If an application needs access to the raw request and response, each is available as an instance variable within the controller.
>
> ```
> PhotosController.show = function() {
>   var req = this.req;  // also aliased as this.request
>   var res = this.res;  // also aliased as this.response
>   this.render();
> }
> ```

So from within your controller, simply:

```
MyController.myAction = function () {
  this.res.send(200);
}
```